# Stripe Payment Intent

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to execute payment with Stripe using paymentIntent. I have read the following in the stripe website ([link](http://Create%20a%20PaymentIntent%20on%20your%20server%20with%20an%20amount%20and%20currency.%20Always%20decide%20how%20much%20to%20charge%20on%20the%20server%20side,%20a%20trusted%20environment,%20as%20opposed%20to%20the%20client.%20This%20prevents%20malicious%20customers%20from%20being%20able%20to%20choose%20their%20own%20prices.))

> Create a PaymentIntent on your server with an amount and currency.
>   Always decide how much to charge on the server side, a trusted
>   environment, as opposed to the client. This prevents malicious
>   customers from being able to choose their own prices.

I do not understand how I can decide how much to charge on the server side. My app has a series of items to buy and each item has a price app is a market place and the price list is in the client, so I decide how much to charge in the client...

Can anyone explain how I can decide how much to charge on the server? or what does it mean, maybe I miss the point?

Comment: Presumably the data on pricing is loaded from a database. The same database needs to feed the payment process. I can’t think of a valid scenario where pricing would be client-only.

Comment: The prices are in a database yes, then they are loaded in the client and the client push them to the server which is where I create the paymentIntent

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is saying not to do what you are doing.

Comment: @theMayer thanks for the feedback. How should the payment process work? the prices are in a Firestore database and I am using firebase cloud function as server

Answer (score 2):

For people who are still looking, you have to store the details of each product in your database and then send the product_id (or any information regarding the product) to the server. Then query the database for the prices of each item stored in your database to get the price. This information should always be in the backend and calculated in the backend itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the `PaymentIntent` in sync with the item(s) your customer is ordering. If they can have a cart client-side where you add items you must be sending a request server-side to update the representation of their cart in your database or similar. At that point, you would calculate the total of the order and keep the `PaymentIntent` updated to reflect the correct total amount.